# Visual Studio - Project missing libraries / Linker problem?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, linker, external-dependencies

I have an issue with the project for university. I am creating a games engine based on C++ with added libraries form glut and SDL. I am using Visual Studio to do it however, it seems that my project has an issue which possibly is the linker.

For short, I am missing libraries even though, they are shown in the tab on the right where all of the files are shown. When i run the program, VS gives up, stops at 555 errors and tells me that I am missing most of my libraries. For some reason I am even missing a ,  and similar basic libraries within the project. I tried going back to previous projects but it seems that they have broken as well. I don't know what to do with this anymore. Any help/advice would be appriciated :)

I sat down with my 2 lecturers, we deleted the .vs and debug files from the project. Retargeted the solution and still nothing. We tried adding all of the libraries and, even adding some updated ones and errors still appear.

I also took a look at "External dependencies" and it seems like all of the SDL2 files are there but, basic files like  are not.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue. It seems like SDL2_ttf wasn't creating a debug file due to a bug in the library. The only answer is to download SDL2_ttf and, any files connected to it. Place the .dll files into the include directory as well as the debug directory. If you get errors that means your files are not compatible with each other.

Many thanks for help :)